# Installing windows service in different machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Context: 
I have developed a windows service in visual studio 2010 (c#) which opens an excel file and close after saving it.

Question:
Is it possible to create any .exe file for this windows service? or
How to install this service to another computer where visual studio is not installed. But I need to run this service in another computer where vidual studio is not installed.

thanks,
pointtoshare

Answer (score 1):

You can add a setup project to your solution and package the service into it.

[Walkthrough on MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169)